# Swift: Property conforming to a specific class and in the same time to multiple protocols

Tags: swift, protocols

In Objective-C, it's possible to write something like that:

```
@property(retain) UIView<Protocol1, Protocol2, ...> *myView;
```

But how can I write this code in swift?

I already know how to make a property conform to many protocols, but it does not work by using the inheritance:

```
var myView: ??? protocol<Protocol1, Protocol2, ...>
```

**Edit:**

I use many `UIView` subtypes  like `UIImageView`, `UILabel` or others, and I need to use some of the `UIView` properties plus some methods defined in the protocols. In the worst case I could create a `UIViewProtocol` with the needed properties, but I would know if it is possible in Swift to declare a property/variable with a type and some protocol to conform with.

Comment: I don't think it's possible like you could in Objective-C. Could you possibly tell a bit more about the protocols? Think there might be a different approach which will be more suitable for Swift.

Comment: I don't understand why you would try to coerce a class like UIView or UILabel to conform to some protocol that it isn't already conforming to, in which case, there's no need to specify it. Are you extending these classes to conform to new protocols?

Comment: @TomErikStøwer I think this is the best solution indeed. I'm still learning Swift and I would know if it was possible like in Objective-C. Yes I extend them to conform to the new protocols so there is no prob.

Comment: @GuidoHendriks the protocols are juste there to help me for some view selections and drag&drop stuff. Like I said previously I'm still learning Swift so I try new things to learn by the same way.

Comment: @YannickL. Ok I see, but if you are already extending those classes, wouldn't then the protocol conformance be implicit from the point of view of the property declaration?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26401778/swift-how-can-i-declare-a-variable-of-a-specific-type-that-conforms-to-one-or-m

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can do this with a generic class using a [where clause](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH26-XID_292):

> A where clause enables you to require that an associated type conforms
>   to a certain protocol, and/or that certain type parameters and
>   associated types be the same.

To use it, make the class your property is defined in a generic class with a [type constraint](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH26-XID_286) to check if the [type parameter](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH26-XID_280) for your property matches your desired base class and protocols.

For your specific example, it could look something like this:

```
class MyViewController<T where T: UIView, T: Protocol1, T: Protocol2>: UIViewController {
    var myView: T

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Great answer. Do you know how this is different from `class MyViewController<T: UIView, Protocol1, Protocol2>: UIViewController { }` ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's exactly the same. I guess I just got caught up in using `where` and didn't try the more concise format.

Comment: In order to use this solution, you'd have to specify the T if you initialize the controller. It's no problem if there is a single object in the property, but in my case I have an array which can contain multiple objects instantiated from different subclasses of the base class. @MikeS How would you approach this problem?

Comment: @LukasKubanek if I understand what you're asking, you can just define the property as an array of `T`s: `var myProperty: Array<T>` or `var myProperty: [T]`

Comment: But in that case you'd have to specify the concrete type when instantiating the container object. See https://gist.github.com/lukaskubanek/ed82cf679c36b5a0b0a1

Comment: @LukasKubanek Ah, I see... I can't think of a way to do that offhand. Like you said, you'd have to pass the concrete type when instantiating the container, so you'd either have to pass `FirstConformClass` or `SecondConformClass` (from your gist) and then you'd just have a container of one of those types, not both.

Answer (score 6):

In Swift 4 it's finally possible. You can declare variable of some class conforming to protocol at the same time, like this:

```
class ClassA {
    var someVar: String?
}

protocol ProtocolA {}

class ClassB {
    var someOptional: (ClassA & ProtocolA)? // here is optional value
    var some: ClassA & ProtocolA // here is non-optional value; need to provide init though :)
}
```

Comment: Could you tell me how to provide that init? I have been trying now for a while without success..

Comment: @jake1981,     init(some: ClassA & ProtocolA) {
        self.some = some
    }

Answer (score 5):

One and probably a bit ugly one of the ways to do that, is to create a wrapper protocol for `UIView`:

```
protocol UIViewRef {
    var instance: UIView { get }
}
```

Now it is possible to create a protocol which implements `Protocol1`, `Protocol2` and `UIViewRef`, which is going to be used to get the `UIView` itself:

```
protocol MyUIViewProtocol: UIViewRef, Protocol1, Protocol2 { }
```

And last step will be implementing UIViewRef protocols for your `UIView`s, which, in you case, as I understand, already implement `Protocol1` and `Protocol2`:

```
// SomeOfMyViews already implements Protocol1 and Protocol2
extension SomeOfMyUIViews: MyUIViewProtocol {
    var instance: UIView { return self }
}
```

As the result we have `MyUIViewProtocol`, implementers of which hold a reference to a `UIView` and each of them implement
`Protocol1` and `Protocol2`. One caveat though - to get the `UIView` itself, we need to ask it's reference from `instance`
property. For example

```
// Lets say we're somewhere in a UIViewController
var views: [SomeOfMyUIView] = // Get list of my views
views.forEach { self.view.addSubview($0.instance) }
```