# Swift: type must implement protocol and be a subclass of given class

Tags: ios, objective-c, inheritance, swift, protocols

In Objective-C, you could define a type as being of a given class and implementing a protocol:

```
- (UIView <Protocol> *)someMethod;
```

This would tell that the value returned by `someMethod` was a `UIView` implementing a given protocol `Protocol`. Is there a way to enforce something similar in Swift?

Comment: Similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25767156/swift-property-conforming-to-a-specific-class-and-in-the-same-time-to-multiple?rq=1

Comment: similar here as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26401778/swift-how-can-i-declare-a-variable-of-a-specific-type-that-conforms-to-one-or-m

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
protocol SomeProtocol {
  func someMethodInSomeProtocol()
}

class SomeType { }

class SomeOtherType: SomeType, SomeProtocol {
  func someMethodInSomeProtocol() { }
}

class SomeOtherOtherType: SomeType, SomeProtocol {
  func someMethodInSomeProtocol() { }
}

func someMethod<T: SomeType where T: SomeProtocol>(condition: Bool) -> T {
  var someVar : T
  if (condition) {
    someVar = SomeOtherType() as T
  }
  else {
    someVar = SomeOtherOtherType() as T
  }

  someVar.someMethodInSomeProtocol()
  return someVar as T
}
```

This defines a function that returns an object of type 'SomeType' and protocol 'SomeProtocol' and returns an object that adheres to those conditions.

Comment: Thanks. In that case, in someMethod if I do: `var v: T; v = MyView()`, I'm getting an error 'MyView is not convertible to T' even though MyView is a `class MyView : UILabel, Protocol`.

Comment: If you add 'as T' to the end of the return it works. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thanks, that's better. I'm still having the following problem in implementing the method:

`func someMethod<T: SomeType, SomeProtocol>() -> T {
  var someVar: T
  someVar.someMethodInSomeProtocol() <-- ERROR "T does not have a member named 'someMethodInSomeProtocol'
  return someVar as T
}`

Comment: Does your protocol actually define 'someMethodInSomeProtocol()'? If I have that define in the protocol and implemented in the class then I don't get your error.

Comment: Yes, it does. But in my case someVar is of type T

`func someMethod<T: SomeType, SomeProtocol>(condition: Bool) -> T   {
      var someVar : T
      if (condition) {
          someVar = SomeOtherType() as T
      } else {
          someVar = SomeOtherOtherType() as T
      }
      someVar.someMethodInSomeProtocol()
      return someVar as T
  }`

Comment: as described in the other thread (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25767156/swift-property-conforming-to-a-specific-class-and-in-the-same-time-to-multiple) it seems that using a where clause solves the issue.

`func someMethod<T: SomeType, SomeProtocol>()` is not the same as `func someMethod<T where T: SomeType, T: SomeProtocol>()`. I don't understand why the latter doesn't work.

Comment: Yeah, I found that after some digging. The interesting thing is when I do that I crash my playground. I'll update my answer with what seems to work and file a bug on the crash.