# Define property that must be a subclass AND conform to protocol

Tags: swift, swift2

In Swift 2.0, how can I do the equivalent of `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSManagedObject*<SomeProtocol> model`?

Basically, I’m trying to define a property on my class that must both be a subclass of `NSManagedObject` AND conform to `SomeProtocol` (I will be calling methods defined by both).

I saw this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25826948/363789, but I'm not sure how I can apply this syntax to property definition...

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think your property declaration in Objective-C is legal.  I find it only works with `id<SomeProtocol>`

Comment: Hmm, you might be right. I suppose that's why there is an NSObject protocol. I wonder if Swift could simply auto-generate an accompanying protocol for each class?

Comment: If that's true, it kind of sucks, as it leads to some annoying casting being necessary

Comment: Can you just subclass NSManagedObject  and make the subclass conform to your protocol?

Comment: Yeah, good workaround I suppose

Comment: Actually in my case it may not be possible (nicely), because I use mogenerator to generate the NSManagedObject subclasses, which my custom code then inherits from.

Answer (score 5):

## Swift 4

This is now possible in Swift 4 using the following syntax:

```
var myObject: NSManagedObject & SomeProtocol
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately Swift doesn't support such type composition yet.

Three reasonable good solutions as workaround (the third one is probably the best):

1.
You can make another type with has those properties and all types **have to** inherit from it in order to be used as `model`.

```
class SomeManagedObject: NSManagedObject, SomeProtocol {
    // conforming to protocol
    func someMethod()
}

// type declaration
var model: SomeManagedObject
```

2.
A more static way to solve this problem is to use generics:

```
class Aclass<T: NSManagedObject where T: SomeProtocol > {
    var model: T
}
```

Note: You don't have to care about another type which has to be the superclass but this solution is not as dynamic and abstract as the one before.

3.
You could also make your own protocol and make `NSManagedObject` conform though an extension:

```
protocol ManagedProtocol {
    // if you want to access some methods/properties directly from the type
    func method()
    var variable: Int { get }

    // otherwise call all methods/properties through "managedObject"
    // this property also reduces casting if you want to have the object itself
    var managedObject: NSManagedObject { get }
}

extension NSManagedObject: ManagedProtocol {
    var managedObject: NSManagedObject { return self }
}
```

Now the type is abstract and can be written as:

```
var model: protocol<ManagedProtocol, SomeProtocol>
```