# Swift 3 Parameter: single variable, two types

Tags: swift, delegates

Anyone know if there's a way to have a parameter be of two types?

Such as for the function:

```
func email(from viewcontroller : (UIViewController, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate) {

}
```

Comment: Are you looking for the `viewcontroller` parameter to accept types that both inherit from `UIViewController` and conform to `MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate`? If so, see [Swift: type must implement protocol and be a subclass of given class](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25825988/2976878)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Genericize your function's definition:

```
func email<T>(from viewController : T) where T: UIViewController, T: MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In Swift 4

```
func email(from viewcontroller : UIViewController & MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate) {
}
```

Elegant, short and intuitive.

Comment: Unless you try with a `CGFloat & Int` -- _Non-protocol, non-class type 'CGFloat' cannot be used within a protocol-constrained type_