# Swift Protocol of a particular class

Tags: swift, protocols

I want to define a variable which of the type `UIViewController` that conforms to `P1`.

**Question:**

- Should I modify the protocol or the v1 type ?
- How should I do this ?

**Code:**

```
protocol P1 {

    func f1();
}


var v1 : P1 //But needs to be a UIViewController which conforms to `P1`
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Swift, how can I declare a variable of a specific type that conforms to one or more protocols?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26401778/in-swift-how-can-i-declare-a-variable-of-a-specific-type-that-conforms-to-one-o)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In Swift 4 you can use the new & sign to make a variable that is conforming a protocol AND a class, the syntax is like this:

```
let vc: UIViewController & P1
```

Answer (score 13):

**As of Swift 4:**

Thanks to [SE-0156](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0156-subclass-existentials.md):

> The proposal keeps the existing `&` syntax but allows one of the elements to be either `AnyObject` or of class type. The equivalent to the above Objective-C types would look like this:
>
> ```
> AnyObject & Protocol1 & Protocol2
> Base & Protocol
> ```
>
> As in Objective-C, the first line is an existential of classes which conform to `Protocol1`  and `Protocol2`, and the second line is an existential of subtypes of `Base` which conform to `Protocol`.

.. we can now declare:

```
var v1 : UIViewController & P1 // UIViewController which conforms to `P1`
```

---

**Prior Swift 4:**

There is no way to directly do that.  You have to either declare `v1` as `UIViewController` or as `P1`, and then use casting (`as`) in order to get to the other functionality.

Closest you can get what you want is with generics.  For example:

```
func testGeneric<T: UIViewController where T: P1>(input: T) {
    input.f1()
}
```

For example, if your case is to have a delegate which is both controller by inheritance and a delegate by protocol implementation, then you can go along these lines:

```
protocol Delegate: class { 
    func doDelegate()
}

class Controller { 
    func doController() {
        print("Controller")
    }
}

class ConcreteController: Controller, Delegate {
    func doDelegate() {
        print("Delegate")
    }
}

class View {
    private weak var controller: Controller? = nil
    private weak var delegate: Delegate? = nil
    
    func setDelegateController<T: Controller where T: Delegate>(delegateController: T?) {
        controller = delegateController
        delegate = delegateController
    }
    
    func test() {
        controller?.doController()
        delegate?.doDelegate()
    }
}
```

And to test this out:

```
let view = View()
let controller = ConcreteController()

view.setDelegateController(controller)

view.test()  // This will print:
             // Controller
             // Delegate
```

Comment: Your solution seems pretty good, but is there a way to declare a variable of that type (generic type). I would need it for delegation

Comment: Yes, in the body of `testGeneric` you can declare a variable of `T` type.

Comment: I mean, without using `testGeneric` function can I declare a variable of the type `T: UIViewController where T: P1` ?

Comment: No there is no such way to do that directly.  But see my edits.  Perhaps this is good enough for your situation.

Comment: Swift 3 format for the func has changed, now looks like this: `func setup<T: Controller>(viewController: T) where T: Delegate`

Answer (score 1):

You can create another empty protocol, constrain `UIViewController` to that protocol, and then use the `protocol<>` directive to combine the two protocols into a single type:

```
protocol UIViewControllerType {} // empty
protocol P1 { ... }

// Make sure only UIViewController adopts UIViewControllerType
extension UIViewController: UIViewControllerType {}

extension UITableViewController: P1 {}

// This works:
var v1: protocol<UIViewControllerType, P1> = UITableViewController()

// This doesn't:
var v2: protocol<UIViewControllerType, P1> = UIViewController()
```

Comment: There is a problem with this approach. Now I wouldn't be able to invoke `UIViewController` methods using `v1` (without casting). I wanted this for delegation mainly.

Comment: That's true. You could add the methods from `UIViewController` that you want to use to the `UIViewControllerType` protocol. But I agree it's not pretty.

Comment: That's a another possibility. True.

Answer (score 0):

What about this way:

```
protocol P1 {
    func f1()
    func getVC() -> UIViewController
}

class MyVC : UIViewController, P1 {

    func f1() {
        // do stuff
    }

    func getVC() -> UIViewController {
        return self
    }
}

var v1 : P1 = MyVC()

v1.getVC() // do UIViewController related things
```

Comment: Swift 4 solution which is marked as answered is the most elegant. Once swift 4 is released, things would be easier.