# Declare metatype that is a subclass and conforms to a protocol in Swift 4

Tags: swift, swift4

> This is NOT a duplicate of [In Swift, how can I declare a variable of a specific type that conforms to one or more protocols?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26401778/in-swift-how-can-i-declare-a-variable-of-a-specific-type-that-conforms-to-one-o). This question is about a specific use case where I needed a metatype and it was definitely not obvious how to do it.

Swift 4 allows declaring a variable that is a subclass and conforms to multiple protocols:

```
var myVariable: MyClass & MyProtocol & MySecondProtocol
```

I need such conformance but not for the instances but for the type itself. But for the following syntax:

```
var classForCell: UICollectionViewCell.Type & AdditionalHeightable.Type
```

gives me this error:

> Non-protocol, non-class type 'UICollectionViewCell.Type' cannot be used within a protocol-constrained type

How can I declare a metatype that is a subclass and conforms to a protocol in Swift 4?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To declare a type that is a subclass and conforms to a protocol in Swift 4 you can use this syntax:

```
var classForCell: (UICollectionViewCell & AdditionalHeightable).Type
```

Comment: I'm answering my own question but it took me hours to find this out. Hope this would be helpful to somebody. I was playing with generics, where this can be expressed as well, but it was limited in other ways.

Comment: Please mark it as a correct answer, even though it is your solution to your question.

Comment: Somewhat surprised that such code even compiles, let alone works! The Swift compiler team might be onto something here... ;)

Comment: When I try to assign the variable as a delegate I get this error: `Cannot assign value of type '(UIViewController & ExperienceDelegate).Type' to type 'ExperienceDelegate?'` Any idea how to deal with this one?

Comment: You are assigning a type where an instance is expected. You probably don't need `(UIViewController & ExperienceDelegate).Type` in your case, but straightforward `UIViewController & ExperienceDelegate`.

Comment: Thank you so much for finding this solution!!!! saved me hours.