# Declare variable of type UIView conforming to a protocol in Swift 2

Tags: swift, protocols, swift2

I need to declare a variable of type `UIView` which also conforms to `MyProtocol`:

```
protocol MyProtocol: class {
    func foobar()
}

class MyClass {
    var myView: UIView<MyProtocol>! // Error: Cannot specialize non-generic type 'UIView'
}
```

However I get the compiler error: Cannot specialize non-generic type 'UIView'.

I need to access methods on the variable from `UIView` and `MyProtocol`.

What is the correct variable declaration to support these requirements?

If it makes any difference, only `UIView` subclasses will implement the protocol. Currently I add protocol conformance via extensions.

I found this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25771265/233602 but it's not clear if that answer is still the best option going in when writing in Swift 2.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make your class a generic class as follows,

```
protocol MyProtocol: class {
    func foobar()
}

class MyClass<T:MyProtocol where T:UIView> {
    var myView: T!
}
```

The error above says that UIView cannot specialise to protocol MyProtocol, so, the solution here would be to make your class a generic class which takes generic parameter which conforms to MyProtocol and is subclass of UIView.

Answer (score 5):

Probably the best way to solve this is to use a protocol where all `UIViews` conform to:

```
protocol UIViewType {
    var view: UIView { get }
}

extension UIView: UIViewType {
    var view: UIView { return self }
}

// the variable
var myView: protocol<UIViewType, MyProtocol>
```

Use the `view` property to access `UIView` specific functionality.

Comment: Notable example of where this isn't adequate is if you need to pass an instance of this protocol to a function that takes `UIView`.

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party here, but [SE-0156](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0156-subclass-existentials.md) (adopted by Swift 4) enables class and protocol composition in type declarations without requiring (resorting to?) generics.

```
protocol MyProtocol: class {
     func foobar()
}

class MyClass {
     var myView: (UIView & MyProtocol)!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> If it makes any difference, only UIView subclasses will implement the
>   protocol.

It makes all the difference! Just do this:

```swift
protocol MyProtocol: UIView {
  func foobar()
}

class MyClass {
  var myView: MyProtocol!
}
```