# Why Doesn't The Swift Compiler Detect Properties of Protocols

Tags: swift, protocols

I am using an NSOperation that conforms to SomeProtocol that has a `results` property

```
let op : NSOperation, SomeProtocol = ...

op.completionBlock = {
    print(op.results)
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Value of type 'NSOperation' has no member 'results'
```

I know that I can subclass NSOperation to get the intended behaviour, but can I achieve what I want using protocols?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That code shouldn't even get that far... unlike Objective-C, Swift does not allow specifying a variable as a combination of both a concrete type AND a protocol.  You can only declare a variable to be of a specific type, a specific protocol, or a composition of protocols, e.g.

```
let op : protocol<SomeProtocol, AnotherProtocol> = ...
```

But there is currently no way to declare a variable as being of the specific type `NSOperation` AND conforming to the protocol `SomeProtocol`

Comment: Interesting, the compiler accepted the variable's definition.

So there's no way to define a variable with a specific type that also conforms to a specific protocol? 

Also, protocols are types, aren't they? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID275

Comment: Thanks for the help! Will accept this as the answer whenever I can

Comment: @GangstaGraham  You can use generics to help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25767156/swift-property-conforming-to-a-specific-class-and-in-the-same-time-to-multiple?rq=1

Comment: I actually tried something similar to generics before I posted the question, I tried to do it like `let op = <T where T: NSOperation T: SomeProtocol>` but that didn't work. Thanks for posting the link. I ended up using subclassing because I needed to use static stored properties which aren't supported in generic types yet

Comment: @GangstaGraham  Yeah, Swift generics are still not complete and you can't have generics constraints in a variable declaration. So that solution won't work everywhere, but it might be a better alternative than subclassing for you.  You could make a `class NSOperationWrapper <T where T:NSOperation, T:SomeProtocol> : SomeProtocol`  Inside that class, you would hold a reference to the real NSOperation and forward methods / property access to the underlying NSOperation. Then you could say `let op = NSOperationWrapper(operation: theOperation)` and use that as your type + protocol